# Im unable to install ADT on Eclipse 3.5

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

Im having a problem regarding installing ADT plugin on Eclipse.
the error prompt was

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
  session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).

Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo/201002260900/aggregate/plugins/org.eclipse.emf.common_2.5.0.v200906151043.jar.pack.gz.
.
.
.

The server download.eclipse.org failed to respond

---

Is there any other location where i can download ADT for eclipse?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is fixed, I was having an error at first because im using the Classic version of eclipse. But when I downloaded the Eclipse JavaEE version the ADT installation worked.

P.S. 
I was using windows here in the office.
Anyways, Thanks for all the replies.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check your network settings as it will not work under proxy or firewall.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/sdk/adt_download.html

Click on the latest version which is ADT-0.9.6.zip as of right now.

Comment: Thanks, for a quick reply but i have followed the instructions for installing ADT when the link 
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
wont work. and i get the same error.

Comment: Which version of eclipse are you using: SE or EE? If SE, try downloading EE and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same problem. The problem resides not in the ADT repository but in the Eclipse (Galileo) repository.

There are certain dependencies for ADT that need to be installed in order to install ADT. At this moment the repository for Eclipse doesn't seem to work. It can't install the dependencies.

So far i have been able to locate some of the dependencies, downloaded them by hand used unpack200 to unpack them and put them into my ~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.5.0_155965261/plugins but i guess they have to be registered somewhere else because i'm stil getting errors on the same file which is actually existing in the plugins directory.

The weird thing is that when i browse to the repository source using Firefox the site does open up. Yet if Eclipse tries to download the required filed it fails, which is not an Eclipse problem because wget or firefox are also unable to get the files.

I've been trying to get it to work for several days now, because i thought that it might be able for download.eclipse.org to be down for a few hours perhaps. Yet it's still not working.

Here's part of the error message i'm getting:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
  session context was:(profile=PlatformProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
  Unable to read repository at http:/ /download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/updates/plugins/org.eclipse.emf.common_2.5.0.v200906151043.jar.pack.gz.
  The server download.eclipse.org failed to respond
  Unable to read repository at http:/ /download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/updates/plugins/org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.5.0.v200906151043.jar.pack.gz.
  The server download.eclipse.org failed to respond

and that list goes on for a couple of more files...

Answer (score 1):

The web seems to be full of people trying to get around the issue of installing ADT on Lucid Lynx.

Ive tried a few things but nothing seems to work for me. The bottomline is just that the Eclipse shipping with Lucid refuses to install any plugins.

I ended up following this tutorial: http://qtcoder.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/installing-android-sdk-on-ubuntu-10-04-lts-lucid-lynx/

This tutorial doesn't install eclipse as a dkpg package but if you just extract it into your home directory and run it from there it works like a charm. If the dpkg is fixed at some point you can always go by removing the manual Eclipse install and install the dpkg instead and things should just continue working as your configuration still resides in ~/.eclipse

Keep in mind that you require the 64 bit version of eclipse if you run the 64 bit version of ubuntu or eclipse won't start.

Happy devving

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully installed ADT on eclipse classic.(Mac)

Select and install the developer tools one by one .It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by going into "Available Software Sites" and unchecking the update site with the numbers at the end of the URL, and checking the one without the numbers.

in my case:

uncheck: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/201206270900
check:   http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/